# How to make a "step by step" element?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm interested in finding out how to make a "step by step" element (sorry, i have no idea what it's actually called). An example would be this: http://www.downloadweb.org/join.php I would like to know how to make that 3 step element. Does anyone know where I can find more info on this?

Comment: What information do you need ?

Comment: Commonly refered to as a Wizard.

Comment: Read the question, I want to know how to make that step by step element

Answer (score 1):

The website you've linked to in your example has done this by creating 3 images - 1 for each "page" of the wizard.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

You simply need to have either:

a) 3 pages which embed the correct image for that page (or, as your example does, 1 script which renders the correct page)
b) 1 Page which dynamically changes the image src depending on what stage of the wizard you're on. This could be done easily with jQuery - there are plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Just see them as 3 different pages. You have to make 6 images (2 for each step, one active and one inactive). Then set the correct classes at each page.

Comment: I know that method, and I have tried it. But I would like to know how to it without redirecting the visitor to a new page. Like, can it be made in a frame?

Comment: You can see, that the site doesnt have new pages for every step.

Comment: @Emily - The page does post back, albeit to the same join.php - which means that they are different pages, just rendered by the same php script.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the 3 step banner above the form? That's created using 3 different images.

You can also analyze websites in your browser. In Internet Explorer  and Google Chrome you can hit F12. For Firefox you can install the "FireBug" extension.
Then you can see the HTML, scripts and stylesheet and everything for the website you're viewing.

Comment: no no, im interested in how it was setup that once you click 'next' you aren't redirected to another page, it changes to step 2 automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Create **3** images (not 6):

> bar_step_1.png
>   bar_step_2.png
>   bar_step_3.png

Then make a `div` or something:

```
<div class="pager step_1">...</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
div.pager {
    height: ...px;
    width: ...px;
}

div.pager.step_1 {
    background-image: url(bar_step_1.png);
}
```